# Why isn't getView being called for every position?

Tags: android, kotlin, baseadapter, android-gridview, getview

I have a simple BaseAdapter for a GridView that of course calls getView for every position in the Grid when clicking on a cell within the Grid. For the most part, getView is called for every position in view (as it should), but sometimes it is only called for the first position. I need this method called for every position in view in order to highlight the selected cell and unhighlight the others but since it is not called for every position, it does not unhighlight the unselected cells.

getView method:

```
class AdapterSelectReference(context: Context, list: List<String>) : BaseAdapter()
{
    override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup?): View
    {
        Logger.log(C.LOG_I, "~*ADAPTER_SELECT_REFERENCE", object{}.javaClass.enclosingMethod?.name + ": start: position = " + position)

        val view: View
        val lrh: ListRowHolder
        if(convertView == null)
        {
            view = this.mInflator.inflate(R.layout.grid_cell_layout, parent, false)
            lrh = ListRowHolder(view)
            view.tag = lrh
        }
        else
        {
            view = convertView
            lrh = view.tag as ListRowHolder
        }
        lrh.label.text = list[position]
        if(position != Settings.referenceSelected.book)
            lrh.label.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"))
        else
            lrh.label.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#E0E7E7"))
        return view
    }
}
```

Activity:

```
class ActivitySelectReference : AppCompatActivity()
{
    lateinit var gvBooks: GridView
    lateinit var adapterBooks: AdapterSelectReference
    lateinit var listBooks: List<String>

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)
    {
        listBooks = resources.getStringArray(R.array.bible_books).toList()
        gvBooks = findViewById(R.id.references_grid_view_books) as GridView
        adapterBooks = AdapterSelectReference(this, listBooks)
        gvBooks.setAdapter(adapterBooks)
        ...
    }   
...
}
```

The log print out that shows only position 0 is called on a certain touch:

```
2020-01-15 09:23:16.376 26646-26646/com.samuelriesterer.custombiblereadingplan I/~*ADAPTER_SELECT_REFERENCE: getView: start: position = 0
2020-01-15 09:23:16.393 26646-26646/com.samuelriesterer.custombiblereadingplan I/chatty: uid=10283(u0_a283) com.samuelriesterer.custombiblereadingplan identical 1 line
2020-01-15 09:23:16.399 26646-26646/com.samuelriesterer.custombiblereadingplan I/~*ADAPTER_SELECT_REFERENCE: getView: start: position = 0
```

Comment: This is impossible to investigate without all of the relevant code.  For example, you did not include the rest of your adapter implementation - the current example does not compile due to missing methods.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of setting background color to `TextView`, set on `view` like

```
if(position != Settings.referenceSelected.book)
    view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"))
else
    view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#E0E7E7"))
```

This will fix the highlight/unhighlight problem

Comment: Actually, this does not fix the issue, which is the getView method is not being called for every visible view; hence the highlighting is not being done every time.

Comment: The issue still persists. The issue is that getView is not being called for every position in the GridView. Sometimes only the first position calls it and all the other views don't.

Comment: It's quite natural. `getView` only calls whenever it needs to draw a view. During scroll, if you scroll 2/3 items then it will call only 2/3 times instead of redraw the whole screen. To get persistent result store your state in a model and based on that change the color instead of `position`

Comment: Yes I know it only draws new views if it is in view and convertView is null. But it should still call getView for every view that is visible. The issue is that it is not called even for visible views. Sometimes it is simply not called, so it does not matter what I put in the method getView because if it is not called, then it will not execute any highlighting.

Comment: I actually figured out what was going on. It's complicated but I was dynamically adjusting the weights of the 3 visible GridViews upon clicking any cell. Most of the time, this updates all the views. But where the GridView weight doesn't change in relation to the others, then it doesn't update. So I just detected such changes and called notifyDataSetChange() on the adapter if needed.